# Toggle a boolean within a struct in zig, possible?

Tags: zig

To toggle* a boolean I normally use boolean = !boolean like this:

```
var boolean: bool = true; 
boolean = !boolean; 
std.debug.print("My bool is: {}\n", .{boolean}); //My bool is: false
```

But how do I achieve this for booleans within a struct? Or is it not possible?

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {

    //Struct with default values:
    const animal = struct {
        tail: bool = true,
        wings: bool = false,
        horns: bool = false,
        paws: bool = true,
    };

    //Struct instances:
    var has = animal{};
    
    //This works alright:
    //var hasno = animal{.tail = false, .wings = true, .horns = true, .paws = false};

    //FAILS: error: expected type 'bool', found '@TypeOf(.enum_literal)'
    var hasno = animal{ .tail = !.tail }; //, .wings = !.wings, .horns = !.horns, .paws = !.paws };


    //Debug printing:
    std.debug.print("Animal has tail: {}, wings: {}, horns: {}, paws: {}\n", .{ has.tail, has.wings, has.horns, has.paws });
    std.debug.print("Animal has no tail: {}, wings: {}, horns: {}, paws: {}\n", .{ hasno.tail, hasno.wings, hasno.horns, hasno.paws });

}
```

Test code for yourself online in zig playground:
https://zig-play.dev

**give it the opposite value of what it was, without knowing what it was.
Like `if (boolean == true) boolean = false; else boolean = true;` But I'm wondering if it is possible with the (bang) operator for booleans within struct.*

Comment: Such questions aren't suited for SO. You'd better off joining Reddit/Discord/Telegram/IRC Zig communities and asking there.

Comment: Alright I'll check that out. Thought it was useful for future beginners to ask 'm here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const std = @import("std");

const Animal = struct {
    tail: bool,
};

pub fn main() void {
    var animal = Animal { .tail = true };

    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{ animal });

    animal.tail = !animal.tail;

    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{ animal });
}
```

Prints:

```
main.Animal{ .tail = true }
main.Animal{ .tail = false }
```

Comment: What I meant with toggle is give it the opposite version of what it was, without knowing what it was. I can accomplish this with an if and else block, but I was wondering if it is possible with the (bang) operator?

Comment: That's it. And when creating a second (opposite) instance: `var hasno = animal{.tail = !has.tail};`. Awesome.